# Query not working on Virtual Layer but working on the real layer

Tags: qgis, filter, virtual-layer

I'm using QGIS 3.10.10 because of project compatibility. I have the following issue with a query used to filter a virtual layer:

If I try to apply a filter to the layer INFRASTRUTTURE as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(L_TOT) FROM (SELECT ((N_TUBI12 - XNTUBI12)*LUNGHEZZA) AS L_TOT
    FROM INFRASTRUTTURE
    WHERE N_TUBI12 <> '0' or N_TUBI12 <> null)
```

I get the error:

> An error occurred when executing the query. The data provider said:
> OGR[3] error 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected
> '(', expecting string or identifier. Occurred around : SELECT
> SUM(L_TOT) FROM (SELECT TIPOLOGIA, N_TUBI12, XNTUBI12, L*

If I try to filter in two steps (creating a new layer L_TUBI_12 in the process to store the result), no error is found and it works perfectly:

```
SELECT ((N_TUBI12 - XNTUBI12)*LUNGHEZZA) AS L_TOT
    FROM INFRASTRUTTURE
    WHERE N_TUBI12 <> '0' or N_TUBI12 <> null

SELECT SUM(L_TOT) FROM L_TUBI_12
```

Now, if I create a virtual layer and I try the first query, no error is shown but the result is NULL. I tried forcing the output as int (because it was Qstring by default) but the result is still NULL.

```
SELECT SUM(L_TOT) FROM (SELECT ((N_TUBI12 - XNTUBI12)*LUNGHEZZA) AS L_TOT
    FROM INFRASTRUTTURE
    WHERE N_TUBI12 <> '0' or N_TUBI12 <> null)
```

The problem seems to be the additional operation **- XNTUBI12** because, if removed, it gives a number as result. The subtract operator is basically not working in the virtual layer.

Do you know why this behaviour? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Did you try to add at the end of your query part `WHERE N_TUBI12 <> '0' or N_TUBI12 <> null)` the string `AS foo`? The result would be `WHERE N_TUBI12 <> '0' or N_TUBI12 <> null) AS foo`. For a subquery, you need to alias your subquery. Does `XNTUBI12` and `XNTUBI12` are both numbers?

Comment: You can force type of `XNTUBI12` with `XNTUBI12 /*:real*/` e.g https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#special-comments

Comment: Hi, I tried forcing type and didn't work. I found a way to make it work using CASE instead of <> NULL. Still, a mystery why the - is not working here though!

Comment: Did you try `IS NOT NULL` instead of `<> NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
WHERE N_TUBI12 IS NOT '0'
```

instead of

```
WHERE N_TUBI12 <> '0' or N_TUBI12 <> null
```

I had a problem with query once, where I had a field called 'Archived' to exclude trees from my map that no longer exist, but wanted to retain their location and data. I recall having the same issue where my query included a

```
WHERE "Archived" <> '1'
```

that didn't give me the expected result.
I tried using

```
WHERE "Archived" is NOT '1'
```

and it worked. Only then I learnt that in SQLITE `<> 'x'` and `IS NOT 'x'` were different. Hope this helps you get closer to solving your mystery.

P.S. I now use `"Archived" is NOT True.`

Comment: Thanks for it, I tried it myself a while ago and it actually solved the problem!